# Get Handle of an Image in memory in C#

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

I have a function that takes in a `Handle` to an image:

```
DoSomethingWithImage( int imageHandle)
{
}
```

In my main, I have an `Image myImage`, which resides in memory.
How can I get a `Handle` to `myImage`, so that I can pass in that `Handle` to `DoSomethingWithImage()` ?

```
    main()
    {
    //memorySTream is a byte[]
    Image myImage = Image.FromStream(memoryStream, true);
    DoSomethingWithImage( ??? );
    }
```

Comment: Why are you collecting an Int if you're passing in an Image?

Comment: DoSomethingWithImage( int imageHandle) is a function from an SDK. I have no idea why they take in an int too. The SDK said the int is a handle to an Image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Image` is just the abstract base class; descendants aren't necessarily guaranteed to even *have* a Windows handle.  You need to know the specific type of image - and so does the SDK you're using, most likely; it is probably assuming that the handle corresponds to a specific format (I would guess bitmap).

If the image is in fact a `Bitmap`, then you would want to use the [Bitmap.GetHbitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz311e4.aspx) method.  On the other hand, if the image is really a `Metafile`, then you need to use the [Metafile.GetHenhmetafile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.metafile.gethenhmetafile.aspx) method to get a handle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was very confused over Image and Bitmap.