# Get Bitmap Handle (IntPtr) from byte[] using C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, image, image-processing

I have a `byte[].` It contains data of an image (jpeg or bitmap) with all the header info.

How can I create a bitmap from that `byte[]` , and obtain a handle to that bitmap?

The important point is, I need to get a handle to that bitmap. The handle I need to get is of type `IntPtr`.

Comment: Is this related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748465/get-handle-of-an-image-in-memory-in-c?

Comment: yes related. The SDK provides another function to get a handle (int) to Image, if I provide it a handle (IntPtr) to a Bitmap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
new Bitmap( new MemoryStream(bytes)).GetHbitmap()
```

?