# What is the equivalent of .Handle (desktop application in C#) in aspx with c# (Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, handle

I am using an example given by Ventana System for the Vensim Software. The example is a desktop application in C#. I want to take this example to a web version in C#.

Desktop version

```
VensimDLLWrapper.vensim_show_sketch(1, 1, 100, (long)pictureBox_Sketch.Handle);
```

Web version

```
VensimDLLWrapper.vensim_show_sketch(1, 1, 100, (long)Image1.???);
```

Comment: There is no Handle sort of thing available in ASP.NET, try to explore Image class, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx

Comment: This link may be of help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748465/get-handle-of-an-image-in-memory-in-c-sharp

Comment: Research how dynamic images are done in ASP.NET. This question is basically a duplicate of that topic.

Comment: Ok, The idea is to use a component like the desktop application for use the handle...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my approach: I create a PictureBox like in Desktop application

```
        PictureBox pictureBox_Sketch = new PictureBox();
        pictureBox_Sketch.Name = "pictureBox_Sketch";
        pictureBox_Sketch.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1200, 768);
        pictureBox_Sketch.TabIndex = 19;
        pictureBox_Sketch.TabStop = false;
```

Then, I put the Image in the Handle.

```
       VensimDLLWrapper.vensim_show_sketch(1, 1, 100, (long)pictureBox_Sketch.Handle);
```

Then , I copy to the clipboard the Image:

```
       VensimDLLWrapper.vensim_tool_command("EXPORT>SK", (long)pictureBox_Sketch.Handle, 0);
```

Finally, I Save the Image In the Disk (It is clear that I have to use Server.Map or other)

```
   if (PInvoke.OpenClipboard(pictureBox_Sketch.Handle))
        {
            if (PInvoke.IsClipboardFormatAvailable(14))
            {
                IntPtr ptr = PInvoke.GetClipboardData(14);
                if (!ptr.Equals(new IntPtr(0)))
                {
                    Metafile metafile = new Metafile(ptr, true);
                    metafile.Save("C:\\ruta\\Images\\ModelGraph.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                    //HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "Images\\ModelGraph.png";
                    // Image1.ImageUrl = "Images\\ModelGraph.emf";

                    //Set the Image Property of PictureBox 

                }
            }
            PInvoke.CloseClipboard();
        }
```